# In Solr, expanding multi-word synonyms and term positions

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a synonym file, used at index time, that contains this equivalence:

```
uc, university of california
```

I then looked at how indexing "uc berkeley" would look on analysis.jsp.  I was surprised:

```
org.apache.solr.analysis.SynonymFilterFactory {synonyms=companysyns.txt, expand=true, ignoreCase=true, luceneMatchVersion=LUCENE_36}
position    1               2               3
term text   university      berkeley        california
            uc              of
type        SYNONYM         word            SYNONYM
            SYNONYM         SYNONYM
startOffset 0               3               3
            0               3
endOffset   2               11              11
            2               11
```

Note that "berkeley" appears in between "university" and "california".  This has meant that, when I search for "university of california berkeley", I don't get a match.  But "university berkeley california" works!

How can I make sure "university of california berkeley" works properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar problem where the highlighted response has the wrong words highlighted. I am using solr 3.6

In my use case have synonyms configured at the indexing side, with expand=true.

For example if I have the following in the synonyms.txt,
dns, domain name system

and I index something like "A sample dns entry that works" . When I search for "name" (without quotes) in the highlighted response I get "A sample dns **entry** that works". As you can see the word entry is highlighted.
Also a search for "system" results in "A sample dns entry **that** works"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a known [problem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3390). There is a fix mentioned (setting luceneMatchVersion to LUCENE_33). Not sure if it works for you. Let's hope they fix it soon.